# I want same value after converting in to double from NSString iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

My NSString value is 28.4701278 after converting into double I want same value as 28.4701278

Comment: what are u getting then? and what did u try ?

Comment: After converting into double, I want same value in double as 28.4701278

Comment: It's just a floating point rounding error.

Answer (score 3):

IEEE 754 floating-point number (used in `double`) cannot accurately represent every single decimal number. See: [Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

If loss of significance is not acceptable, use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `double`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringValue = @"28.4701278";
double doubleValue = [stringValue doubleValue];
```

Comment: NSString *stringValue = @"28.4701273";
double doubleValue = [stringValue doubleValue];  the out put will be : 28.470127300000001

Comment: Not same  28.4701273

Comment: in my case output is same as above... can share your code where you are using it?

Comment: Please show your out put console.

Comment: i think you only need double data structure while performing some mathematical operation and for tht 28.470127300000001 is almost equal to 28.4701273. and if you want to display it anywhere than you can again convert it to string and it will be 28.4701273. for conversion from double to string you can use 
        NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [fmt setPositiveFormat:@"0.#######"];
        NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:doubleValue]]);

Answer (score 1):

simple try

```
double finalValue = [@"28.4701278" doubleValue];
NSLog(@"final value ==%f",finalValue);
```

you get output like

[image]

**Update**

```
 double finalValue = [@"28.4701273" doubleValue];
 NSLog(@"final value ==%f",finalValue);
```

I get output like

[image]

**Edit**

use `NSDecimalNumber`  instead of `double`

```
 NSDecimalNumber *decimalNum= [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"28.4701273"];
NSLog(@"final  ==%@",decimalNum);
```

output is

[image]

Comment: use it @"28.4701273" instead of @"28.4701278"

Comment: bro 3 is missing in your out put.

Comment: @SalmanAli -- check the **Edit** answer bro..

Comment: This is object type not double data type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var string = "28.4701278"
var a = Double(string)
```

[image: Output]